# Cucumber Test execution for gradle project via command line using tags for cucumber feature files

Tags: gradle, command-line, cucumber

I am looking to execute a cucumber test for a gradle project via command line using specific feature tags.

The command I am using: `gradle test -DCucumber.options="-tags @tagname"`.
Command does execute the tags mentioned.
I have tried using gradle test `-DCucumber.options="-tags @tagname"` and also `gradle test`. I didn't find any difference in both the command.

`gradle test -DCucumber.options="-tags @tagname"` executes the Runtest.java  and tags mentioned in this file, irrespective of what feature tags I pass via command line for example: tagname.

Runtest.java

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src\\test\\resources\\featurefiles", monochrome = true, plugin = {
        "com.eis.listeners.ExtentCucumberFormatter:" }, glue = {
                "com.adminconsole.stepdefs" },tags= {"@adminconsolelogin,@devicemanager,@certificatemanagement"} ,format = { "json:JsonReports/AdminConsole.json" })
```

So here I have mentioned three tags in the Runtest.java.
Now, instead of running all the tags, I wanna run a specific tag via command line.
Command: `gradle test -DCucumber.options="-tags @adminconsolelogin"`, but `-DCucumber.options="-tags @adminconsolelogin"` part ain't working.

I am looking for a solution where we can run specific tags irrespective of what tag is mentioned in Runtest.java. More precisely pass tags dynamically via command line.

But `-DCucumber.options="-tags @tagname"` ain't working via command line.
Would appreciate if anyone can provide me with a correct command or strategy or code on how to do it. If the below command is wrong: `gradle test -DCucumber.options="-tags @tagname"` please correct me.

Comment: Have you tried `test { systemProperties 'Cucumber.options', '-tags @<the tag>'}`?  I'd think that would produce identical behavior, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update: For Cucumber 6 you need to provide the following statement:**

```
test {
systemProperty "cucumber.filter.tags", System.getProperty("cucumber.filter.tags")

}
```

You have to bridge the system properties between the gradle JVM and the forked JVM for the tests for this to work.  From issue [#1346](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1346#issuecomment-382769136):

```
test { 
    systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.getProperty("cucumber.options") 
}
```

Add that to your build.gradle and then you can do it on the command-line:

`gradle test -Dcucumber.options="-tags @tagname"`

Comment: Thank you!!! @Nick Rundle. This works.
The correct command : gradle test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @tagname"

Comment: But what we would put in RunnerClass, because its the only mapping for gradle to running environment but its not going to RunnerClass. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this

```
test { 
systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.getProperty("cucumber.options")
```

}

And CLI command will be

```
gradle test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @tagName"
```