# TestNG with Cucumber Gradle, not able to overide cucumberoptions from command line

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber, testng

IDE: IntelliJ
Build Tool: Gradle
Test Framework: TestNG with Cucumber

I have CucumberOptions specified in my runner class.  I am looking to override it from command line and provide different tags.  So many videos and help i saw and followed but can't seem to make it work.  My project just contains gradle.properties file and no testng.xml or cucumber.xml file.  The command line i have been trying to use >>>> ./gradlew test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @something".  My runner class looks like this....

```
@CucumberOptions(tags = "@nothing"
        , features = {"src/test/resources/features"}
        , glue = "steps"
        , plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber-report.json"})
@Test
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

My build.gradle file looks like this.....

```
test {
    systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.getProperty("cucumber.options")
    useTestNG()
    jvmArgs(["-Ddataproviderthreadcount=${System.getProperty("threads")}","-Dcucumber.options=${System.getProperty("cucumber.options")}"])
    scanForTestClasses = false
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    systemProperties System.getProperties()

}
```

What am i missing?  Hoping that someone with new set of eyes will see what i am not seeing.  Really appreciate whatever help i can get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cucumber Test execution for gradle project via command line using tags for cucumber feature files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376470/cucumber-test-execution-for-gradle-project-via-command-line-using-tags-for-cucum)

Comment: Thanks so much Andrey.  I did come across this article too.  I did what it says but still the tags is not getting overridden.  This is how my changed build.gradle file looks like now....

test {
    systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.getProperty("cucumber.options")
    jvmArgs(["-Ddataproviderthreadcount=${System.getProperty("threads")}","-Dcucumber.options=${System.getProperty("cucumber.options","tags = @developers")}"])
    useTestNG()
    scanForTestClasses = false
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
}

Comment: Hopefully the following link to the solution would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70631614/cannot-pass-cucumber-options-from-command-line-with-gradle