# Cannot pass cucumber.options from command line with gradle

Tags: gradle, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am creating serenity + gradle + cucumber6 test framework. Everything works fine but I get error when I want to send cucumber options from the command line:

```
gradle  test  -Dcucumber.options="--tags @SmokeTest"
```

I get error:

```
Task '.options=--tags @SmokeTest' not found in root project 'MySerenityRestStarter'.
```

In build.gradle file I have:

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
    systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.getProperty("cucumber.options")
}
```

Any advice?

I use Gradle 6.8.3

You can see complete build gradle file or checkout project here https://github.com/draganstanisavljevic/serenity-cucumber-restapi-starter

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

In build.gradle:

```
sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11
test {
   systemProperty "cucumber.filter.tags", System.getProperty("cucumber.filter.tags")
   testLogging {
    showStandardStreams = true
   }
}
```

Here is how u pass the tags:

```
gradle test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@SmokeTest"
```

[image]

Comment: I tried thanks. Now, I get error:
 Could not find method testLogging() for arguments [build_rwhyjlll1rkzydb0my9u6z5e$_run_closure6@c97220] on root project 'MySerenityRestStarter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: Can you try without the testLogging block and let me know if it works, mean while I will try to find what is missing for testLogging that u see this error

Comment: I tried without testLogging and I get error Task '.filter.tags=@SmokeTest' not found in root project 'MySerenityRestStarter'.

Comment: Hi @DraganStanisavljevic, 

I cloned your GitHub project and did the new changes (please refer my answer) and it worked. I have attached an screenshot from the report generated by your framework......

New changes in answer: 

1. Changed source and target compatibility to 11 (I think 14 should work as well, better to verify which version is installed in your machine. For me it was 11) 
2. For the `testLogging` block you were getting error because previously by mistake I wrote it outside `test` block but it's part of `test` block Kindly check with the changes and let me know if it worked

Comment: hi, just curious if it worked?

Comment: Hi Prashant. Unfortunatelly, no. There is an error no "Task '.filter.tags=@SmokeTest' not found in root project 'MySerenityRestStarter'."

Comment: However, before to reply I wanted to check from command line and it works from command line. Even with previous version:
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
    systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.getProperty("cucumber.options")
}
 from command line everyhtnig is ok. It seems it is issue with IntellyJ

Comment: Error is present when I run command from terminal in IntellyJ. I invalidated cache many times and clean project but error is always present.